# $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ from the measure theory perspective.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $X:[0,1]² \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:[0,1]²\to \mathbb{R}$ random variables(i.e measurable functions), we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $$m(w; X(w) \in A, Y(w) \in B) = m(w;X(w) \in A)m(w;Y(w) \in B) \ \forall A,B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$ Being $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ the borel sigma algebra and $m$ the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]²$.

I am trying to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $$E(X)E(Y) = E(XY)$$

My attempt: I proved this for simple functions. Then for $X$ and $Y$ positive I consider two increasing successions $\psi^x_k, \psi^y_k$ converging c.t.p to $X$ and $Y$ respectively and then I use the monotone convergence theorem. The problem here is that this succesions doesn't have to be independent and then I can't say $E(\psi_k^x)E(\psi_k^y) = E(\psi^x_k \psi_k^y)$.

My attempt to fix this was using Egorov Theorem to say that this successions converge "almost uniformly" but i didn't manage to do something.

Some idea to fix this ? or to prove it by another way?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use Fubini.

Comment: But how can i use fubini in $E(XY) = \int XY$ ?

Comment: I added an answer. Please do let know if anything is unclear.

Comment: If you look carefully at the standard construction of simple function approximation for non-negative random variables, you will see that $\psi^X_k$ and $\psi^Y_k$ can indeed be taken to be independent.

Comment: Yes!!! I discover that yesterday. That is because the sets used in the construction are preimages of the function. Then we can consider a succesion of simple functions made with sets which are preimage of X. The same for Y, but these sets are independet among them!

Comment: I will post it as an answer but I dont know if it is okey that I answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the end my initially idea works! The proof is easy if one assume $X$ and $Y$ being simple functions. Now if we consider $X$ and $Y$ being positive variables, the theorem follows from consider simple functions converging to $X$ and $Y$. For this is essential for the simple functions to be independent, then the crucial question arise, given $X$ and $Y$ independent, can one construct a succesion of increasing simple functions $\varphi^X_n$, $\varphi^Y_n$ converging to $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and such that $\varphi^X_n$ and $\varphi^Y_n$ are independent? As someone in the answers points out, the usual construction works! Let's see:

For $X$ let $\varphi^X_n(x) = \frac{i}{2^n}$ for $x$ st $f(x) \in (\frac{i}{2^n}, \frac{i+1}{2^n}]$ with $0\leq i < 2^{2n}$ and if $f(x)>2^n$ then $\varphi^X_n(x) = 2^n$. One can see that this is the standart construction. One can consider $\varphi^Y_n$ in the same way. Now the crucial observation is that the characteristics of the simple functions aproximating $X$ are using sets which are preimages of Borel Sets of $\mathbb{R}$, indeed they are essentially $X^{-1}((a,b])$, the same is valid for $Y$, but this sets are independent among them!, i.e, the preimages of $X$ are independent of the preimages of $Y$, this follows from the definition of $X$ and $Y$ being independent variables. Then, this simple functions are independent, because the preimages of $\varphi^X_n$ belongs to the preimages of $X$, the preimages of $\varphi^Y_n$ belongs to the preimages of $Y$, and the preimages of $X$ and the preimages of $Y$ are independent! then the preimages of $\varphi^X_n$ and the preimages of $\varphi^Y_n$ are independent among them, but this means that $\varphi^X_n$ and $\varphi^Y_n$ are independent. Then the magic of the monotone convergence theorem follows:

$$E(\varphi^Y_n\varphi^X_n) \to E(XY)$$ but $$E(\varphi^Y_n\varphi^X_n) = E(\varphi^Y_n)E(\varphi^X_n) \to E(X)E(Y)$$ then $E(X)E(Y) = E(XY)$.

For the general case one can descompose $X$ and $Y$ in their positive and negative part.

Answer (score 1):

$$E[XY] = \int_\mathbb{R} E[Xy]P_{Y}(dy) = E[X]\int_\mathbb{R} y P_Y(dy) = E[X]\int_\Omega Y(\omega) P(d\omega) = E[X]E[Y]$$

---

I used the following lemma, which is an easy corollary of Fubini and a change of variable:

Let $X,Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ random independent variables and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ Borel-measurable. If $f \geq 0$ or $E[|f(X,Y)|] < \infty$

Then

$$E[f(X,Y)] = \int_\mathbb{R} E[f(X,y)]P_Y(dy)$$

Apply this with $f(x,y) = xy.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions to understand it. FIrstly, Minkowski says $||x+y||_p \leq ||x||_p + ||y||_p$ but does not tell you something about a product. Am I missing something with this?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant hölder. It's a while since I did measure theory. I silently, of course, assuumed that both variables are integrable.

Comment: Dont worry!! But Holder just tell you $\int |XY| \leq ||X||_p||Y||_q $ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ and this is not the case. I think we must assume that $X$,$Y$, $XY$ are integrables. ¿What do you think? I think in the case $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}$ which is integrable in $[0,1]$ but $g^2$ does not.

Comment: Ok. You are right. I was somewhat too fast there. Holder doesn't apply. But you can use the lemma I wrote down with $f(x,y) = |xy|$, do the calculations, and it will become integrable. Applying the lemma we get $E[|XY|] =  E[|X|]E[|Y|]$ and the integrability follows from that.

Comment: Okey. I am trying to understand the proof, is taking me a while because I don't know the notation. First is $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}$? I wonder this because the integral you take in the lemma is over $\mathbb{R}$.  Maybe I am getting confused with $()$ which i don't know very well what it means

Comment: $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is the probability space I work on.

Comment: $P_Y$ is the image measure defined by $P_Y(A) = P(Y \in A) = P(Y^{-1}(A))$ where $A$ is a Borel set of the real numbers. Thus $P_Y$ is a measure on the real numbers with the Borel sets.

Comment: Are you familiar with these notions?

Comment: I am not!, sorry but at the moment I dont know abstract measure! That is because I just consider the lebesgue measure in my problem and the space $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Why do you ask for a measure theoretic solution then?

Comment: Because my answer stay in the lebesgue measure in a real space.

Comment: Do you at least know that $E[X] = \int_\Omega X dP?$

Comment: Yes, of course, just i would say  $$E(X) = \int_{[0,1]²} X dm$$ being $m$ the lebesgue measure in $[0,1]²$

Comment: That doesn't make any sense? On what probability space are you working? On $[0,1]^2$ with the Borel sets and lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes, ([0,1]², $\mathcal{B}([0,1]²)$, m) being $m$ the lebesgue measure. ¿What it is wrong?

Comment: No, but why would you restrict to that particular probability space? Nevertheless, the proof remains the same. Just change $\Omega$ into $[0,1]^2$, $P = m$ and $P_Y = m_Y$ where $m_Y(A) = m(Y \in A)$

Comment: Because I do not know abstract measure theory yet. If I take $f(x,y) = xy$ the lemma would be $$E(X,Y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 X(x,y)Y(x,y) dxdy = ...$$ and then I get lost in how to prove it and in understand it